# boost::shared_ptr circular dependency

Tags: c++, tree, include, shared-ptr

I have a question, I implemented a tree using different classes at each level. 
The pointer to the tree items are boost::shared_ptr<>.

Because each level stores a pointer to the parent and a pointer to its children there is a circular dependency in the header files.

The code looks like this:

```
//A.hpp
class A
{
    List<boost::shared_ptr<B> > children;
};

//B.hpp
class B{
   boost::shared_ptr<A> parent;

};
```

Because I use boost::shared_ptr I cannot use forward declaration in B.hhp. But I don't know how to solve this problem. It would be nice if you could help me.

Comment: Hint: Do the children own the parent?  If not, then why do they have owning pointers to the parent?

Comment: of course the children should not own the parent, do I need another kind of pointer for this one?

Comment: Why not a regular pointer to class A?

Comment: I can not use regular pointers to a object, when I use shared_ptr to the same object.

Comment: @Thorsten: Yes you can, as long as they don't share in the ownership.  And since they don't own the parent...

Comment: I guess using boost::weak_ptr is the cleaner solution?

Comment: @Thorsten why not use unique_ptr here instead ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Because I use boost::shared_ptr I cannot use forward declaration in B.hhp

This is not true. Declaring a `shared_ptr<>` should not require the pointed type to be complete:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class A;

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<A> pA; // OK
}

class A { };
```

Your problem is not with mutual dependency on header files. You definitely *can* use forward-declarations to break those dependency.

The problem you are having is circular referencing between objects that keep each other alive. To break this cycle, use `boost::weak_ptr`.

Also, C++11 introduces the standard class templates `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` (defined in the `<memory>` header), so unless you're working with C++03, you should consider using these class templates instead of Boost's ones.

```
//A.hpp
class A
{
    List<boost::shared_ptr<B> > children;
};

//B.hpp
class B{
   boost::weak_ptr<A> parent;
};
```

Comment: This solution seems to compile, I haven't check the dependencies yet. Thank you and all the others for the quick responses. It should learn more about smart pointer now ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [`boost::weak_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm) in `B` to break the cycle:

```
//A.hpp
class A
{
    List<boost::shared_ptr<B> > children;
};

//B.hpp
class B
{
   boost::weak_ptr<A> parent;
};
```

It can be [converted](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm#lock) to `boost::shared_ptr<A>` with the `lock()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The pointers from child to parent (those that go "up" the tree) should be [boost::weak_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm)s instead.  That will effectively break your circular dependency, while still keeping the parents accessible via boost::shared_ptrs (via the weak_ptr::lock() function).

Answer (score 0):

This is classical with smart pointers. You have to somehow use `weak_ptr` in some direction to break the dependency.

The way it works is that `weak_ptr` does *not* hold a reference to the pointed object. But you can get a `shared_ptr` at any given time by calling its `.lock()` function. You have to be careful though not to call `.lock()` *after* the `shared_ptr` somehow expired.

The way I use this mechanism is as follows: you always keep a `shared_ptr` from your parents to your children, and you always keep a `weak_ptr` from your children to your parents. So you never have a circular dependency since you cannot do a hard link going back in your hierarchy.

This way makes sense (but it could vary depending on your particular situation): if the child exists, then the parent must still exist and thus calling `.lock()` on the `weak_ptr` will not fail.

You can learn more on `weak_ptr` and such in the [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm).